# Importing using MySQL WorkBench... error ERROR 1046 (3D000)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1046

Scenario: building a RoR enviroment locally for development. Production is on EngineYard / GitHub. All now working ok, except DB isn't importing.

I have a .sql file that i've taken from my prod EY site. Now i need to import it to my MySQL locally. I'm using Workbench (as i'm new to this), but getting error below.

Please help?

> 08:07:43 Restoring /home/james/Downloads/Futology.sql Running: mysql
>   --defaults-extra-file="/tmp/tmpAVeE58/extraparams.cnf"   --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "/home/james/Downloads/Futology.sql" ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 22: No database selected
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1 08:07:43 Import of
>   /home/james/Downloads/Futology.sql has finished with 1 errors

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not used Workbench too much however it's easy enough to do from command line have a look at [this](http://www.techiecorner.com/31/how-to-restore-mysql-database-from-sql-dump-file/) (below phpMyAdmin instructions)

The command you're after is:
`mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#`

Comment: I don't have a dump file, it's a .sql file which isn't letting me import. The imported DB is called company_production. I assume i need to create a DB somewhere called company_production then import? If so, how!? Thanks

Comment: A DB dumpfile is just a list of SQL statements used to create your schema and populate data. The .sql file you have should be the dumpfile and contain such statements. You are correct, you will need to create your database first. Again I'm not familiar with the Workbench tool but following the instructions here: [create db - mysql command line](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-creating-database-and-table/) you should be able to create the database. Exit from the MySQL Command Line Client (by typing 'exit') then type the following: mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#

Answer (score 46):

Workbench doesn't know the database (schema) you want to use.

In workbench, when using Data Import/Restore, just below where you choose the file to import, it asks "Default Schema to be Imported To"

Just choose the database (schema) you want it to use from the dropdown titled Default Target Schema. If you don't have a database (schema) already, you can create it with the "New" button.

This is confusing because MySQL generally seems to use the term database but Workbench uses schema.  They mean the same thing for most purposes. [MySQL 'create schema' and 'create database' - Is there any difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219711/mysql-create-schema-and-create-database-is-there-any-difference)

Answer (score 10):

Simply by choosing your target schema

[image: Simply by choosing your target schema]

**As I circled in above image**

Answer (score 8):

Similar to brynn's answer, simply modify your SQL file and insert the following line at the very top:

```
use yourdatabasename
```

Replacing `yourdatabasename` with the database into which you are trying to import.  Also, this database should already be created (albeit empty) before you import into it.

Comment: This is the answer to the question, if you need to use Workbench.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option that worked for me. I'm using MySQL 5.5 on a VM I set up for importing a large MySQL .sql dump that contained: 1). a create table statement 2). insert statements for inserting a large amount of data into the table. 
at the MySQL command line client prompt type:

```
use yourdatabasename
source d:\yourpath\yourfilename.sql
```

for more info on the 'source' and other commands, enter ? at the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

The above command line is correct. I found I have to do this when importing .sql files from older versions of MySQL. I also found I had to edit the .sql file (top of the file) and set the db name to be the same as the blank db you create before doing the import.