# How to copy a database(Mysql) to another computer including columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a simple desktop application project on NetBeans using java.The database for that project was created in another computer.so i wanted to get it on my PC.Therefore i copied the database folder(simsdb) from the other PC and copied back to my MySQL database location.   (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data)Then i connected it.But the problem is all the database tables are visible but non of the columns can be found..!(unfortunately I'm having lack of reputations to upload my problem snapshot) Plz can anyone help me...?

Comment: You might get your approach to work, but it would probably be easier to export the database and import the resulting SQL file on your computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***How to copy a database(Mysql) to another computer including columns?***

***Try something like this:***

```
mysqldump -u root -p lbry > dump-lbry.sql
```

***Then to import it:***

```
mysql -u root -p < dump-lbry.sql
```

*you should try this method, And there have lot of method to copy the database. if you wants to see the another style or method goto use the below link, and this will definitely going to solve your problem*...

***click this link>https://stackoverflow.com/a/22447694/3242978***

Comment: @dgcharitha, look at my answer it will solve your doubt and you should must try this link...