# Are schemas used in other DBMS' than SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sqlite, postgresql, schema

Since SQL Server 2005, [schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) are acting as root namespaces for objects (tables, views, etc).

My question is: are there equivalents in other DBMS'? I'm particularly interested in:

- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html), Oracle, SQL Server

  - Schemas are Supported
- MySQL:

  - No support for schemas; [`create schema ...` is a synonym for `create database ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219711/mysql-create-schema-and-create-database-is-there-any-difference).
- SQLite

  - No support for schemas; `create schema ...` causes an error.

**Edit**: I used OMG Ponies' answer to update above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [PostgreSQL supports schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html) though I don't know when support started.  Oracle supports schemas as well.

MySQL does not -- [CREATE SCHEMA is an alias for CREATE DATABASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219711/mysql-create-schema-and-create-database-is-there-any-difference).  I don't know about SQLite, but given its limited support I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Schemas have been in PostgreSQL since [version 7.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-createschema.html), [released on 2002-11-27](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-7-3.html).

Comment: I'd almost argue that in MySQL there's only one database and `CREATE DATABASE` is a synonym for `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Comment: I second Craig's take on this.

Answer (score 4):

Other DBMS that support schemas

- [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_schemaqualifiers.htm)
- H2 Database
- HSQLDB
- Apache Derby
- LucidDB
- Mimer SQL
- Vertica

DBMS that do *not* support schemas:

- Firebird
- Cubrid
- Teradata (CREATE SCHEMA is a synonym for CREATE DATABASE)