# CREATE SCHEMA IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I have used the Create Schema in mySQL. But it act as a separate database. It doesn't affect the already created Databaase. How to create Schema in mySQL within an particular database in mySQL and need to group the tables within a schema.?

Can anyone know about this pls...??

Answer (score 2):

I believe from recent experience and from a quick Google on the subject that a Schema IS a database in MySQL unlike other databases where the two are different. See the following links:

[MySQL 'create schema' and 'create database' - Is there any difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219711/mysql-create-schema-and-create-database-is-there-any-difference)

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/211616

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CREATE SCHEMA/CREATE DATABASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html) and the [USE dbname](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/use.html).

Comment: i used the below codes to create schema in mysql               mysql> CREATE USER 'some_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'some_user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;