# How to convert MS SQL queries to MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server, converters

I have a MSSQL queries file(.sql), now I need to convert it to MYSQL queries.
Please help me. The script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Artist](
    [ArtistId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

(
    [ArtistId] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: That looks like DDL, not a Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert the DDL by hand, then you can do this by building up rules on a case by case basis, e.g. as follows:

- `[]` need to be replaced with backticks
- IDENTITY(1,1) can be replaced with `AUTO_INCREMENT`
- Most of the ANSI options and Device settings
  can be ignored (these seem to be present only because the table has
  been rescripted)
- w.r.t. `dbo`, MySQL doesn't implement schemas in the same way as SQL [Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219711/mysql-create-schema-and-create-database-is-there-any-difference) - you will either need to separate schemas into databases, or drop the schema, or mangle the schema name into the tablename (e.g. as a Prefix)

This will leave you with something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `Artist`(
    `ArtistId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name` nvarchar(120) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
       `ArtistId` ASC
    )
);
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca37f)

However, it is usually much easier to do this migration with a [migration tool](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/move_from_microsoft_SQL_Server.html) - search for the section on How to `Transition from SQL Server to MySQL`