# List of databases in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to get a list of all databases in SQLAlchemy? I need a cross-database solution, so basic "SHOW DATABASES" doesn't cut it.

Similar to MetaData/Inspector capabilities to show all tables and columns.

Comment: How can you be simultaneously connected to multiple databases? You usually hardcode it.
Oracle is a database, MySQL etc... in the documentation of SQLAlchemy, you can find the list of databases it supports.
You are most likely mixing a database with schema. 
As far as I remember there is no Russian doll database, that is there is no such a thing as databases within a database.

So either you are looking for the databases supported by Alchemy, OR you are mixing the definitions.

Answer (score 26):

Looks like I found the answer myself.

There is a method called [get_schema_names](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_schema_names) in Inspector class, which is not very well documented, but returns list of databases (just tested with MySQL and Postgres).

**Usage:**

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
engine = sa.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@localhost')
insp = sa.inspect(engine)
db_list = insp.get_schema_names()
print(db_list)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - but this doesn't return a list of databases. It just returns the list of schemas on a single database. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Comment: Coud you tell us which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: It is working with MySQL but not PostgreSQL whenever I am using this connection string   postgresql://user:pwd@localhost

Comment: To echo @Guy, this returns a list of schemas, not databases. I think OP has mixed up their labeling of schemas vs databases.

Comment: This is the top voted answer... but it does not work and does not answer the OP's question

Comment: This works at times, while other times it throws: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 122: unexpected end of data`.  Not sure why this behavior is so chaotic.

Comment: @Guy what do you mean by schemas on a single database? Database is the software and schemas are the tables and relationship containers.

Each schema in a database, defines the tables and their relationship with each other.

Comment: @Ash wow, 7 years ago :) a database is ambiguous. Actually, you have a database, which lives within a database server. You could have 1 or more. In each database you can have 1 or more schemas. Each schema is, essentially, a container of tables, objects and relations. The above snippet is a list of schemas and not of databases (which may or may not be what you are looking for).

Comment: @Guy The OP might be ambiguous but database is not ambiguous. If this was the case we should throw all books written away and dismiss all university courses as well as SQL.

Comment: @Ash when you "database" you could mean a "database server" that can contain several databases, and a database instance. When you spin up a PostgreSQL server, you can create several databases on it. In any case, the OP asked for a list of databases, in the connected server. The above solution does not provide it. It provides a list of **schemas**, which aren't databases.

Comment: @Guy you can keep insisting on this forever but the definition is what I said. Educate yourself on RDBMSs first. You can have multiple databases of MySQL for example but they must be individual installs with different configurations. There can only be one database, within that database we have schemata. That’s the classic definition and the only correct term. Anything you see in documentations are actually wrongly written.

Comment: @Ash in a single install of a PostgresSQL server (or any other platform probably) (I dropped the word database for you) you can have **multiple** databases. Each database is NOT a single install. Within each database you can have multiple schemas. The OP asked about the "SHOW DATABASES" command, implying they're interested in listing databases, and not schemas, so this answer we are commenting on, is simply not relevant.

Comment: @Guy Don’t spend credits on my behalf! You dropped it because you are wrong as well as whoever says “multiple databases within a database”. 
I see no point in arguing this any further. I stand 100% correct. It is impossible to have multiple databases under one database. What you and many are referencing to is either schemas or “lack of education”.

Comment: @Ash I never once said that a database can have multiple databases. Obviously, you didn't read my comments. I said that a single **server** can have multiple databases. And each database can have multiple schemas.

Comment: @guy There can only be 1 database. What's the point of having 10 databases? All can be handled with schemas. Anything beyond this is not standard. SQLAlchemy is an ORM and "CREATE DATABASE" command does not align with its purpose.

Comment: @Ash I just hope that people reading your comments don't get fooled. If you install any server (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.) (try it: `docker run -d postgres`), you have one admin database, and you can create additional databases (e.g. per domain). You can manage things by schemas, sure. It's all use-case-dependent. No one was talking about an ORM. Few example of servers that supports multiple DBs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html , https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-databases/ .

Comment: @guy Having multiple databases requires individual instances (installed or not installed). It is not part of the RDBMS itself. It is an added feature.
In Oracle for example you can have multiple databases with different connections and prefs(not possible in Postgre) but those are not part of any standard RDBMS. 
Standard SQL statement to return the names of "SQL databases" is not defined. There is no universal definition of an RDBMS having multiple instances (and it doesn't matter).
This has nothing to do with ORMs and RDBMS.
The OP clearly wants a list of schemas no "databases".

Comment: @guy All that said, one must never refer to the documentation of a software as a reference. That's why I said you must educate yourself first and then start arguing.

In MySQL, you can only have schemas and "databases" is interchangeably used across its documentation. Therefore the concept of multiple databases like PosgtreSQL is non-existant there. We have only schemas in MySQL.


My reference is the standard/classical/text-book definition of a Relational Database  Management System.
Software specific features should not be mixed up with what an ORM should/must do.

Comment: @guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219711/mysql-create-schema-and-create-database-is-there-any-difference

Answer (score 4):

```
engine.execute('SELECT datname FROM pg_database;').fetchall()
```

Every entity in DB is saved in some "system" table. For example,  in Postgres you can get all DBs from pg_database table.

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: You are hardcoding the DB type (postgree) in your code which is wrong. There is no point in using an ORM if you hardcode things the way you did.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution i came up with for mysql:

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    eng = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306', pool_recycle=3600)
    q = eng.execute('SHOW DATABASES')
    available_tables = q.fetchall()
```

It does an execute and returns all of the rows.