# Use sqlite3 for prototyping in a flask app

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am creating the prototype for a webapp using flask,
flask-sqlalchemy and some toy sqlite3 database.

I am using sqlite3 databases just for development purposes, but ideally
I would like to use some different SQL database in production.

What I am finding hard to understand is how to use SQLalchemy and sqlite3 in a way that I won't have to rewrite my queries once I use the production database.

A silly example: in mysql I can get a list of all the databases available (whose names I use to populate a "drop menu") using "SHOW DATABASES ", but in sqlite I have to do this by listing all the files in a directory.

What is the best way to prototype a webapp using sqlite3, without having to rewrite all the queries after?

Comment: Why would you need to get a list of databases dynamically in your web app? Normally you'd only have a single database.

Comment: Hi Daniel, unfortunately I won't have only one database, I will have to aggregate data from different databases.

Comment: Fair enough, but you should recognize that this is not the typical use case for something like SQLAlchemy, so it is unlikely to be able to help you paper over the differences between db systems.

Comment: so you would recommend setting up a mysql database for development purposes as well?

Comment: In general it's a good idea to use the same database software for development that you use in production. When you don't, you increase the chances that things that work in one environment won't work in the other.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689895/list-of-databases-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: In theory, you wouldn't need to change queries if you sqlalchemy. You just need to switch database connections by this documentation:http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html

Comment: @DanielRoseman the question you posted is quite related, however I do not want to know how list the schemas (for example) but rather how to organize my sqlite databases so that they would resemble a production environment (if possible, if not I might consider some different solution).