# Structure of T-SQL tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am switching from `MySQL` to `SQL Server` for a new job and I have encountered something I don't quite understand as I haven't encountered something like this before.

I am using the WideWorldImporters Microsoft [Sample DB](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/wide-world-importers-v1.0) for reference.

Looking at the table structures I can see that it is `SCHEMA_NAME.X.TABLE_NAME`

**Example**

```
[WideWorldImporters].[Application].[Cities]
```

In `MySQL` this would just be `schema.tablename`

**Example**

```
[WideWorldImporters].[Cities]
```

What is this middle part (the [Application] part in the example) exactly? I can't seem to find anything about it but that's likely because I don't know what it is to look for.
It's obviously important as a select query won't work if it's removed. Can anyone explain or even name this so I can research it?

Comment: The three part naming is **not** `SCHEMA_NAME.X.TABLE_NAME` - it is `DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME` - just use `SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME` unless you are actually doing cross database queries

Comment: This gets a little confusing, but what MySQL calls a "schema" SQL Server calls a database. SQL Server has its own, separate notions of schema that is loosely tied to ownership. So `WorldWideImports.Application.Cities` is the table `Cities` in the schema `Application` in the database `WorldWideImports`. Three-part names should not normally be used since databases should ideally not depend on each other. (They should especially not be used within the database *itself*, since then code will break in a most ugly and unnecessary way if the DB is renamed.)

Comment: Relevant Documentation: [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL) - Multipart Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#multipart-names)

Comment: @jeroenMostert Ah Ok that makes sense  thank you ! I suspect this wont be the last puzzling difference between the two that I will encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft uses a three-part naming pattern of `Database_Name.Schema_Name.Table_Name` that differs from the MySQL convention. In general terms, a MySQL "schema" is roughly equivalent to a SQL Server "database."

In practice, one should avoid explicitly referencing the database name unless specifically needed.

Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#multipart-names

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add some extra details on [`paneerakbari` Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999727/1908296)

**First:** About `SQL Server` according to [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#multipart-names) Transact-SQL has different formats to define Object name (Table name), Here are supported formats

| Object reference format | Description |
| --- | --- |
| server.database.schema.object | Four-part name |
| server.database..object | Schema name is omitted. |
| server..schema.object | Database name is omitted |
| server...object | Database and schema name are omitted. |
| database.schema.object | Server name is omitted. |
| database..object | Server and schema name are omitted. |
| schema.object | Server and database name are omitted. |
| object | Server, database, and schema name are omitted. |

For case you can use Two Formats, `database.schema.object` OR `database..object` **Examples:**

```
[WideWorldImporters].[Application].[Cities]
```

OR

```
[WideWorldImporters]..[Cities]
```

**Second:** About MySQL, the Schema name is Synonymous with the Database name So There is two SQL formats `database.object` OR `object`, Here are useful links describe Whats differents between Schema and Database in MySQL [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219723/1908296) And [TutorialsPoint Question](https://tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-schema-and-database-in-mysql)